# How to dynamically allocate string using void function?

Tags: c

**First of all Thanks for visiting my question... :)**

I am interested in competitive programming, so I daily do some amount of problem-solving, however, I only know C language at a decent level, and I often face problems while dynamically allocating something as usual, especially for strings and 2D arrays.

But I somehow manage to find ways (thanks to StackOverflow), for example, I wanted to create a function that scans string dynamically until the user enters space or new line, so I came up with the solution below and it works perfectly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
char *create_string(char *ptr)
{
    ptr = (char *)malloc(0 * sizeof(char));
    unsigned int size = 0;
    char c = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == 32 || c == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
        size++;
        ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, size * sizeof(char));
        ptr[size - 1] = c;
    }
    ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, (size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    ptr[size] = '\0';
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = create_string(str);
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("\n%lu", strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
```

And now for curiosity purposes, I want to know how can I do this same thing using the void function?, something like:

```
char *str;
create_string(&str);
```

should start storing everything in the dynamic memory which is pointed by str.

Also, please if you have more knowledge to show in DMA for 2D array, then please show me it, feel free to give examples with different problems.

And also How can I stop scanning the string (which was allocated dynamically) with specific string ending? for example, scanning(any kind of scanning, i.e. int, bool, custom structures etc...) should stop if user enters string "STOP", Please feel free to give pictorial examples.

Because I am sure that this question is burning like a fire in beginner's and intermediate C programmers' minds.

Comment: Back in the day, a `void` function was called a `subroutine` and was used for what are termed `side effects`... One advantage of writing functions that returning values is that they can become building blocks. `y = f(x)`... Functions _should_ return useful values, imho.

Comment: @Fe2O3 IIRC, [BITD C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K&R_C) did not have `void`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "Back in the day" (and more so now), C wasn't the only kid on the block, and "subroutine" was part of common parlance.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Agree about _subroutine_.  Question availability of _keyword_ `void` function`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Is returning void an oxymoron?  The C 2017 curiously talks about it.

Comment: Suggest `getchar()` (or `getc(FILE *stream)` or `fgetc(FILE *stream)`) instead of variadic `scanf()` with `"%c"` format specifier. Further how long can your non-whitespace containing string be? Longest word in unabridged dictionary is 29-characters, longest in medical dictionary is 45-characters. Even if you can have up to 8K characters or more, consider a single read into automatic storage with `fgets()` (or `scanf("%[width-1]s", ..)`) and then allocate and copy to new block rather than `realloc()` every char.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hmmm, `s` in `"%[width-1]s"`??

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - the *Field-Width* modifier.... sorry that was unclear. I though about trying some other way to set that off in fixed text -- but that was the best I cam up with...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As C passes arguments by value, to return something via an out parameter, you need to pass in a pointer to it.  So to return a `char *` it would:

```
void create_string(char **s) {
  *s = malloc(42);
}
```

Here is your refactored code.  I changed the following:

1. Eliminate return value of update caller.
2. Initialize `*ptr = malloc(1)` for the trailing '\0'.  It eliminates an unnecessary and implementation defined  `malloc(0)`.  This also eliminates the `(*ptr)[size] = ...` which looks wrong as the last index is expected to be `size - 1`.  Alternatively initialize it to `NULL`.
3. Use character constants instead of magic values (32, 10).
4. `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 so leave it out.
5. Reduced scope of variable `c`.
6. `free()` memory allocated.
7. (cosmetic) Use `size_t size` instead of `unsigned int size`.
8. (cosmetic) Avoid the noise of casting casting `void *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_string(char **ptr) {
    *ptr = malloc(1);
    size_t size = 1;
    for(;;) {
        char c;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') break;
        (*ptr)[size-1] = c;
        size++;
        *ptr = realloc(*ptr, size);
    }
    (*ptr)[size-1] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char *str;
    create_string(&str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(str));
    free(str);
}
```

I didn't fix these issue:

1. Check return value of `malloc()`, `realloc()`.
2. `v = realloc(v, ...)` is unsafe and will leak memory if `realloc()` fails.  You need to do `char *tmp = realloc(v,...); if(!tmp) { // err }; v = tmp;`.
3. Check return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be  operating on uninitialized data.
4. Use `scanf("%s", ..)` instead of `for(;;) { scanf("%c", ...)`.  It's more efficient to allocate a chunk at a time instead of per byte.
5. If user enters `ctrl-d` (EOF) the program will go into an infinite loop.
6. It's good idea to separate i/o from logic (i.e. let caller do the `scanf()`.  That way `create_string()` is much more reusable.

Comment: That's not working, I've replaced ptr with *ptr at code shown in question, and passed &str as aarg, used the prototype as void creat_string(char **ptr), its resulting in error "Segmentation fault".

Comment: @SohamJobanputra Does your updated code have `*ptr[size] = '\0';`?

Comment: @SohamJobanputra I am not able to reproduce your segmentation fault (see above).  Please supply stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, @AllanWind , you solved that issue!